# How to detect media keys without MediaSession API?

Tags: javascript, keycode, mediasession

I am trying to detect the events from a blutooth media controller with Play/Pause buttons and volume up/down buttons. For volume up/down I catch 174 and 175 event keyCodes using **keyup** listener but for play/pause It not works. I found that the standard way is to use MediaSession Api ([This doumentation](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5639924124483584)).

Besides I found this website https://keycode.info/ which provides the event keyCodes for all input types. I checked the [source code](https://keycode.info/scripts.js?v=06272019) and found that it **is not using** MediaSession but catches play/pause events as well. It seems that only touchstart,onkeydown and onkeyup are being tracked but Play/Pause is being detected with **keycode 179**. Can anyone tell me how it works?